# Is there a keybinding to resize window to half of Width size in Gnome of Debian 8?

Tags: debian, gnome

Similarly as in Ubuntu 16.04, I think by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>arrowLeft/arrowRight</kbd>. I just moved away from Ubuntu 16.04 because of many stability issues, but I cannot find such a feature in Gnome3.

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Debian: 8.5 with Linux kernel 4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MATE desktop environment + Compiz Grid plugin to get this result.

Comment: MATE is a (active) fork of Gnome2 (which is not in development any more), Compiz is the windows manager which work with MATE. Where do you use Gnome2 ?

Comment: Gnome 2 is discontinued, it's probably Gnome3 fall back mode  or classic shell (or what ever they call it now), just Install MATE desktop and you'll get the Gnome2 experience and use compiz for getting the desired behaviour for the window manipulation using shoutcut-keys.

Comment: Yes, Debian 8.5 is with Gnome 3.14. Let's hope Gnome 3.20 has something for this next february.